# With WORKBENCH, connect to an external database (on OVH with phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, database-connection, mysql-workbench

So, I'm trying to connect to my database.

I'm trying to do it with workbench.

So :

[The error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG2Yi.png)

What I did :

[In workench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw6ik.png)

I put the password of the database after clicked on "ok".

I also tried to put lereseq995.mysql.db instead of Hostname : 127.0.0.1

I put the password and

I Get a similar error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1iEs.png)

(I put the password of the database after clicked on "ok")

So, if someone can help me please... I'm looking for an issue since 3 hours...

Comment: Is the external database configured to accept direct remote connections?

Comment: I checked it and no... you're right.

Comment: So I've got a new database still on OVH.

I have the same problem...

I do some tests and I'll reply here later with some screens if I don't get throught these errors...

Comment: Hello, So I tried many things.

Comment: I buy a database that allow external connexion.

I connected this one to a website (for a test) and it works. You can check blog-motivation.com 

But when I try to connect with workbench, I got this error : Unable to connect with localhost.
And there is only this message.

So, should I install something ? like xampp or wamp sever ?? I don't understand everything about this... I hope someone could help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Workbench runs on your computer, not on the remote server, so you need to specify the remote host's IP address or host name.

Comment: Hi, yes, I did it. It works. Thank you.

Comment: please write the error message as text rather than posting as picture, as it may help other users who encountered same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem,

I just added my public IP into the white list of authorized IP to connect to the database.